# Determine why an element receives focus?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, focus

We have an app that manages focus pretty meticulously and recently I've found a bug that causes some element to become focused unexpectedly. I've been pulling my hair out looking for the source of this issue. Is there some way we can determine *why* an element is being focused/what code is initiating that?

I've added a `focus` event listener, but I can't find any clues even in the `event` object it receives.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to track this down? We're using React, in case there might be any hidden tricks or tools I'm overlooking.

Comment: You must have used .focus() on it in the code somewhere. Can't tell for sure until you provide a minimal reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: Not the case... A dependency perhaps, but that's the entire point of my question - tracking it down...

Comment: Ammm. not sure but, why don't you, after the 3rd party `.focus()` happens, - go to Developer tools, Event listeners tab, click the Focus dropdown and inspect.

Comment: That's an event listener. That will only tell me what's listening for focus, not what's causing focus.